# Redirect and show notification if form submitted

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to redirect the page after form submitting and then to show some notification.

Here is my code:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("UPDATE something.....");

$_SESSION['message'] = "Updates Successfully";
    header('location: index.php');
    exit(0);
```

And also notification script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $("#success_msg_1").click(function(ev)
            {
                ev.preventDefault();

                var opts = {
                    "closeButton": true,
                    "debug": false,
                    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-left",
                    "onclick": null,
                    "showDuration": "300",
                    "hideDuration": "1000",
                    "timeOut": "5000",
                    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                    "showEasing": "swing",
                    "hideEasing": "linear",
                    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                };

                toastr.success("So me by marianne admitted speaking.", "This is a title", opts);
            });

        });
    </script>
```

But the page is just redirecting and no notification there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notification is set on a button click event. If you want to show a notification when the new page loads then you should put your toastr notification in the document ready, not inside the button click event.

Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {

                var opts = {
                    "closeButton": true,
                    "debug": false,
                    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-left",
                    "onclick": null,
                    "showDuration": "300",
                    "hideDuration": "1000",
                    "timeOut": "5000",
                    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                    "showEasing": "swing",
                    "hideEasing": "linear",
                    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
                };

                toastr.success("So me by marianne admitted speaking.", "This is a title", opts);

        });
    </script>
```

Also make sure that you included [both the CSS and JS files for toastr](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/toastr.js/latest) in your .

Comment: so how can I call this script in php function if form submitted?

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear. In your post you are saying you want to show a notification after the redirect, not on form submit.

Comment: I am really sorry for misunderstanding. I need to show notification after the page redirect and if form submitted with success or not. I mean if success there will be one notification message, if not success then another notification with message. How should I call it in php function?